# ¿Valdurán o baldurán?

Tags: vocabulario, etimología, ortografía

Primero un poco de contexto. En mi región, León (España), tenemos la expresión familiar `ser un baldurán`. Un baldurán es una persona que no se preocupa de sus asuntos con la debida atención. Otra posible acepción de "baldurán" le da el significado de "revoltoso", "travieso" o "trasto".

Nunca he visto esta palabra escrita y el [DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/baldur%C3%A1n) tampoco la reconoce.

Mi pregunta es doble:

1. ¿Cómo se escribe: valdurán o baldurán?
2. ¿En qué otras regiones se utiliza la palabra `baldurán`?

**ACTUALIZACIÓN 2014-02-25**

Puesto que ni `valdurán` ni `baldurán` aparecen en ninguno de los diccionarios o corpus que he consultado, voy a proponer que las respuestas sugieran una posible etimología para esta palabra.

Por ejemplo, aunque existen un gran número de topónimos escritos con `v` (Valdepeñas, Valdefuentes, Valderas...), la etimología de muchos de ellos ("Valle del") no es relevante. Por otra parte, sí que es posible encontrar en el diccionario de la [RAE](http://dle.rae.es/baldado) palabras que empiezan con `bald~` cuyo significado sería más próximo, como por ejemplo:

```
baldado (Del part. de baldar).
1. adj. Cansado, fatigado.
2. adj. Pan. tuberculoso (‖ que padece tuberculosis). U. t. c. s.
```

Otro tipo de información que también ayudaría serían ejemplos de uso del sufijo `~urán`.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN 2014-03-02**

He mejorado la definición de baldurán. La anterior definición no era completamente correcta.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN 2014-03-03**

En el diccionario solamente he encotrado otra palabra que termine en `~urán`:

```
ardurán (Del ár. marroquí eddṛa, y este del ár. clás. ḏurah; cf. port. adora).
1. m. Variedad de la zahína de Berbería.
```

El diccionario etimológico, conocido como [el Corominas](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diccionario_cr%C3%ADtico_etimol%C3%B3gico_castellano_e_hisp%C3%A1nico), lista una acepción muy divertida. Habla de "valura", "baldura" o "balura", indistintamente: perteneciente a un valle muy remoto de Galicia donde había muchos curanderos. Dice el diccionario que los curanderos se esparcieron por las provincias vecinas y que hacían encantamientos.

Comment: ¿Qué región es?

Comment: @JoulSauron, acabo de actualizar la pregunta para responderte

Comment: No lo había oído en la vida.

Comment: @Bardo, es una palabra que solamente he oído decir a personas de cierta edad. Gijón, por su proximidad geográfica con León, podría compartir su uso, pero me temo que las generaciones más jóvenes estamos perdiendo una parte importante del vocabulario que nuestros mayores usaban.

Answer (score 1):

Soy de Perú y nunca en mi vida había escuchado esa palabra. Tengo entendido que las palabras que no son aceptadas por la RAE no tienen restricciones de escritura, puesto que se puede regir por las normas del español ya que no pertenece al idioma. Así que, hasta que aparezca oficialmente en el DRAE puedes escribirla como crees que se escriba y que suene igual a lo que pronuncias.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. He actualizado la pregunta para sugerir otros tipos de información me ayudarían a decidir la ortografía de esta palabra.

Answer (score 1):

1. I could only find one reference to *baldurán* online:

   > **Baldurán**   Persona que anda perdida, -ido
   >
   > - [Algunos localismos de la tierra de Tábara](https://www.tuvozdigital.com/index.php/local/nuestras-cosas/1910-xx-algunos-localismos-de-la-tierra-de-tabara)

   It also appears as a person's name in the [11th October 1921 edition](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/pdf.raw?query=parent%3A0000730691+type%3Apress%2Fpage&name=La+Voz+(Madrid).+11-10-1921) of *LA VOZ*<sup>1</sup>:

   > ... Cipriano Pérez Baldurán, de Gerona...
2. *Valdurán* however is a village in Alba de Tormes<sup>[2](https://callejero.openalfa.es/alba-de-tormes) [3](http://www.villaalbadetormes.com/doc/memoria.doc) [4](https://cartographic.info/espana/map.php?id=848395)</sup>.

---

<sup>1. *LLEGADA DEL "CLAUDIO LOPEZ" A VALENCIA - Expedición de heridos y enfermos de Melilla* (front page article)</sup>

Comment: Just for the record. Tábara is a town in the province of Zamora (bordering Leon).